How can a combination of a green object and a gray object be missed?
I'm writing a clicker that clicks on all falling green objects. He should not click on blue or gray objects. BUT, when there is a combination of green and gray, the program clicks on it, but I need to exclude it
def find_contours():
    screen = sct.grab(monitor)
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask_for_green = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_green, upper_green)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_for_green, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    return contours

This code takes a screenshot of the screen and outlines all the green objects. Well, then I’ll bring them back and start clicking on them.

This is what it all looks like with the contours already selected

I've been at this task for a long time and can't seem to eliminate them. I tried creating a mask for the gray to exclude it, but it still highlighted it. This is roughly what I tried to do
mask_for_green = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_green, upper_green)
mask_for_gray = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_gray, upper_gray)

combined_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask_for_green, cv2.bitwise_not(mask_for_gray))

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(combined_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


A pixel is either green or gray, so bitwise_and() operations will never solve this issue for you, since they look at pixels individually. What you need to do is identify individual objects (anything that is gray OR green), and discard the ones that contain any gray pixels in them.

You could look at the bounding boxes of your contours and check if they contain any gray pixels. There is potential for false positives if green and gray objects are really close to one another without actually touching but it should work reasonably well.
